# invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python

I continue to get this error with a currency converting program I wrote

```
baht = raw_input("enter baht")
usd = int(baht) / (30.94)
print "%r baht equals %r usd" % (baht, usd)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what value you are using when running your script and you get the error?  This works fine for me if I enter in a valid integer like "17".

Comment: Let me guess, you entered a float expression such as `10.00`?

Comment: Why do you want to make the number of baht into an integer?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe His raw_input's output is a string.

Comment: But why an integer and not a float?

Answer (score 2):

Issues:

1. use float(baht) as bath it will probably be an interest rate, which is not int.
2. don't raw input stuff with comma (,) as a decimal separator, use dots (.)